# How to join two dataframes, keeping only rows with the same entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. My original one (df1) and a grouped one (df2) originating from df1.
I want to join them together but keeping only the rows from df2 but with all columns of df1. So basically all values in each row in df2 need to match in df1 to keep the row. I tried using `merge` but I could not figure out how to do it unfortunately.

These are my two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A1',  'B2',  '2010-12-06', '2014-03-14',  'E1',  'F1',   'G2'],
    ['A2',  'B2',  '2014-04-13', '2017-10-01',  'E2',  'F2',   'G2'],
    ['A3',  'B2',  '2017-11-01',  None       ,  'E3',  'F3',   'G2'],
    ['A10', 'B10', '2010-12-06', '2014-03-14 ', 'E10', 'F10', 'G10'],
    ['A11', 'B10', '2014-04-13', '2017-10-01',  'E11', 'F11', 'G10'],
    ['A12', 'B10', '2018-11-01',  None,         'E11', 'F12', 'G10'],
    ['A14', 'B14', '2010-12-06', '2014-03-14',  'E14', 'F14', 'G14'],
    ['A15', 'B14', '2016-04-13', '2017-10-01',  'E15', 'F15', 'G14']], 
   columns=['Baum1', 'Baum2', 'date1', 'date2', 'Baum5', 'Baum6', 'Baum7'])
```

The second one is basically just 4 rows of df1.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['B2',  'G2', '2010-12-06', '2014-03-14'],
    ['B2',  'G2', '2014-04-13', '2017-10-01'],
    ['B2',  'G2', '2017-11-01',  None       ]], 
   columns=[ 'Baum2','Baum7',date1, date2])
```

So what I want the final dataframe to look like:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A1',  'B2',  '2010-12-06', '2014-03-14',  'E1',  'F1',  'G2'],
    ['A2',  'B2',  '2014-04-13', '2017-10-01',  'E2',  'F2',  'G2'],
    ['A3',  'B2',  '2017-11-01',  None       ,  'E3',  'F3',  'G2']], 
   columns=['Baum1', 'Baum2', 'date1', 'date2', 'Baum5', 'Baum6', 'Baum7'])
```

I could just add all columns manually to df2 but my original dataframe has 62 columns so this is not an option.
Any approaches to this problem or ideas are welcome!

Comment: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='right')`